# I can't get what I type in the input value

Tags: php, phpmailer

Everyone, I'm having a boring problem.
I have a contact form and when I send a contact email, the email even arrives, but the values ​​of the input's are not passed except the message.

I get the message like this:

Contact site

```
Name:
Email:
Message: (here I get what I write in the message input)
```

However, what I type in the Name, e-mail and Subject I do not receive, it appears blank.
Could someone help me please?

Here is my form code:

```
<form id="contactform" name="contactform" action="email.php" method="POST" >
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- <label for="fname">First Name</label> -->
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- <label for="email">Email</label> -->
            <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- <label for="subject">Subject</label> -->
            <input type="text" id="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Assunto">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- <label for="message">Message</label> -->
            <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Mensagem" required></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Envie sua mensagem" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my PHPMailer code:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
 try {
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'conta***@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = '(my supa password)';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('lv***@gmail.com', 'Leo');
    $mail->addAddress('lv***@gmail.com', 'Leo');

    $mensagem = "<strong>Contato site</strong><br><br>";
    $mensagem .= "<strong>Nome:</strong> " . $_POST['name'] . "<br>";
    $mensagem .= "<strong>E-mail:</strong> " . $_POST['email'] . "<br>";
    $mensagem .= "<strong>Mensagem: </strong> " . $_POST['message'] . "<br>";

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $mail->Body    = nl2br($mensagem);
    //$mail->AltBody = $mensagem;

    if($mail->send()){
        $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'OK', 'mensagem' => 'E-mail enviado com sucesso!'));
        header('Location: /agradecimentos.php');
    }else{
        $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ERRO', 'mensagem' => $mail->ErrorInfo));
        header('Location: /error.php');
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ERRO', 'mensagem' => $mail->ErrorInfo));
    header('Location: /error.php');
  }
}
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: `input`s are passed by `name` attribute to sever. __Unless__ you have some javascript magic.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot! Sorry for the nonsense!!!!!

Comment: IMPORTANT -- You should immediately edit your message, delete ID (login/password) and change your conta***@gmail.com password.

Comment: This password is not the real one! But thank you for the tip!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"message" is the only form element with a `name`:

```
<textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Mensagem" required></textarea>
```

So it's the only one being sent to the server.  Give `name`s to your other form elements as well:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" required>
... etc.
```

The `name` has to match the key you're using to get the value on the server:

```
$_POST['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace following lines

```
<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" required>
<input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" required>
<input type="text" id="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Assunto">
```

with

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" required>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" required>
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Assunto">
```

Comment: Yeaaaah! Thanks!! Thank you! I forgot! Sorry for the nonsense! Thanks Naveed!

Comment: You are welcome.